# C - Can't find memory leaks (Valgrind)

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm new at covering memory leaks and I'm concerned about the problem of leaks. I'm using Valgrind.

I've solved most of it ye't I cant pinpoint where the last (14) leaks come from as I feel I'm freeing all allocated memory.

I've tried to go through all my mallocs/callocs without success.
I've debugged for a while but no progress.

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
==9664==     in use at exit: 85 bytes in 14 blocks
==9664==   total heap usage: 105 allocs, 91 frees, 182,137 bytes allocated
==9664== 
==9664== 85 bytes in 14 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==9664==    at 0x483877F: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
```

```
void readline(FILE *file) {
   char line[120];
   while (fgets(ligne, 81, file)) {
      replace_words(line, words,  &i);
   }
}
```

Comment: `strdup()` in `placermots_tabs()` it says. Trace all dynamic data allocated at that place.

Comment: It *tells you* where they were allocated. Is that useful?

Comment: Lisa, `char **words = calloc(nb_mots, size * sizeof(char *));` is suspicious.  Why the `size * sizeof(char *)` multiplication for a 1D array of `char *`?

Comment: 81 in `char ligne[80]; while (fgets(ligne, 81, file))` is certainly wrong.  Why 81 when the buffer is only 80?

Answer (score 2):

Within the function `placermots_tabs` there is used the function `strdup` that dynamically allocates memory and returns a pointer to the allocated memory. And the allocated memory was not freed when the created character array by the function strdup  was not required any more.

Here is the function

```
void placermots_tabs(char ligne[80], char **words, int *i) {
   char *word = strtok(ligne, " ,.-\n");
   while (word != NULL) {                  // strtok result controls the loop
      words[(*i)++] = strdup(word);
      word = strtok(NULL, " ,.-\n");
   }
}
```

Within the while loop there are dynamically allocated character arrays using the function `strdup`.

```
words[(*i)++] = strdup(word);
```

You need to track correctly the allocated memory: whether it was freed.

It seems the reason of the memory leak is the while loop within the function `lire_lignes`

```
void lire_lignes(FILE *file, char **words, int *nb_mots, struct Stats *stats) {
   int i = 0;
   char ligne[80];
   while (fgets(ligne, 81, file)) {
      placermots_tabs(ligne, words,  &i);
   }
   effacer_doublons(nb_mots, words);
   stats->mot_sans_doublons = *nb_mots;
   trouver_lettre_frequente((char const **) words, stats);
   fclose(file);
}
```

where the function `placermots_tabs` is called that overrides anew the array pointed to by the pointer `words`.